# Force applied in box2d object after collision

Tags: box2d

I have a projectile and a tower. When i hurl the projectile it strikes the tower. Based on projectile force the tower is broken. Now I need to know how to get the force that is applied to these 2 object when they collide(not before collision, rather after collision). I know in the following method they are calculated-

```
void MyContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse *impulse)
{
    force=impulse->normalImpulses[0];
}
```

this gives me the overall force applied, But i want to know the individual force applied to 2 different object.

And another question , this method reside in the subclass of b2ContactListener class. How to pass this value to gameScene where object will be destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The same impulse is applied to both bodies (in opposite directions of course).
2. You will need to have a variable which is visible to both the PostSolve callback and wherever else you need to use it - a global or class variable could be used.

Comment: If I have multiple object colliding then how to identify distinct impulse from this variable??

Comment: You will need to check which fixtures are colliding - you can get them from the contact like contact->GetFixtureA() and contact->GetFixtureB(). If it helps, you can set something in the user data as a tag to differentiate them. See the implementation of BeginContact in this tutorial, it's kinda similar: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks

Comment: Thanks for that link. But if Object A collide with with Object B and Object C at the same time then i will get 2 impulse for A. So object A will have 2 impulse , so user data tag for object A will not suffice. Any other idea??

Comment: Why does it not suffice? If object A is the tower and the sum of the two impulses is enough to break it, then it should break.